# Django: How to sum downvote and upvote elements of a model in models.py and not in views.py?

Tags: python, django

I have a NewLink model which has 3 different IntegerField attributes, one for downvotes, one for upvotes, and the last one for the sum of the two up and down fields. I know how I can sum the two fields in my views file each time I need the ‘linklikessum’ element, but I do not know how to easily code that right into the model. I’d obviously prefer to have the summation just hardcoded as the property of the linklikesum element so I do not have to do something like `Foo = NewLink.objects.get(pk=X)` and then `Foo.upvote + Foo.downvote` Can someone help me out so I don't have to do this every time? Thanks in advance

For reference, here is the model itself:

```
class NewLink(models.Model):
    upvote = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    downvote =  models.IntegerField(default=0)
    linklikessum = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    url = models.URLField(null=True)
          “””. . .more stuff…“”” 

        def __unicode__(self):
            return.self.url
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless this total is expense to calculate, I wouldn't store this in the database, just make it a property of the model. Ex:

```
class NewLink(models.Model):
    upvote = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    downvote =  models.IntegerField(default=0)
    @property
    def votetotal(self):
        return self.upvote + self.downvote
```

But if it *is* expensive to calculate, you can do this in the model's save() method, ex:

```
class NewLink(models.Model):
    def save(self, *args, **kw):
        self.votetotal = self.upvote + self.downvote
        super(NewLink, self).save(*args, **kw)
```

Comment: Can you tell me a bit more in detail when would be a good time to use the model's save() method? When you say expensive, do you mean in terms of CPU usage if many NewLinks are being loaded at once on a page?

Comment: Expensive could mean mathematically complicated. It could also mean that you need to perform a bunch of joins across multiple models. In the example presented, it won't be expensive to do it as a property because you've already loaded the record and it's a trivial operation to add two fields. A related question is the relative frequency of viewing vs. saving... in many cases, you view a record more than you save it, but that would depend on your intended usage. It's a good idea to get familiar with profiling tools and techniques and let those be your guide as to what needs optimization.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. I appreciate the explanation. So in my template, I can no longer access the "votetotal" field in your example by simply doing {{newlink_instance.votetotal}}, right? Because that gives me an error. How can I access the votetotal field in my templates after calling an instance of the object?

Comment: Also, for example, what would be the equivalent of using the order_by sorting argument in the backend. Something like this gives me an error: NewLink.objects.all().order_by('votetotal')

Comment: @SwAvGuy That would be the correct way to do it on a field, as it would be ordered on the database side. To sort on a sum or other calculation, you'd need to use annotate first. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#annotate

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, you would need to create what's called a Method. A Method is a function within a a model. Rather than do three IntegerFields, use only two and do something like this.

```
class NewLink(models.Model):
    upvote = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    downvote =  models.IntegerField(default=0)
    url = models.URLField(null=True)
      “””. . .more stuff…“”” 

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.url

    def link_likes_sum(self):
        return self.upvote + self.downvote
```